# How to retrieve data from three different collections in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have below three collections:

### Student collection:

```
{
id: "123",
name: "Surendra",
Age: "21"
}

{
id: "125",
name: "Reddy",
Age: "21"
}
```

### Department Collection:

```
{
studentId: "123",
department: "CSE",
hod: "Ramki"
}

{
studentId: "125",
department: "EEE",
hod: "Ramki"
}
```

### College collection:

```
{
studentId: "123",
collegeName: "SKU",
city: "HYD"
}

{
studentId: "125",
collegeName: "SKU",
city: "HYD"
}
```

Q: So, I need to fetch name, department and collegeName fields related to particular studentId from the three collections.

Is it possible to generate using the Query? if not can U pls generate it using JAVA.

Comment: have you tried anything? what problem you are facing?

Comment: I think your "real" problem here is learnig  to adapt your "SQL relational" thinking to using a "NoSQL" document store. Where practical you should not be thinking relationally, but rather "embedded" as a document store allows. If this is not even a fit at all, then you should be using a relational store instead.

Comment: Please read [ask] for how to write a good question. [so] is not here to write your code for you!

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for joins in Nosql, which every newbie tries to look into.A Query on multiple collections is not possible but.... The nearest possible solution could be something shown in this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YFcYoxlB74

Comment: Ok but can we try using Java. Please correct me if wrong.

Comment: The thing shown in that video is more like java if i'm not wrong. MongoDB is not meant to normalize your tables and use joins. Instead make them into a single collection. Its all about how u model your data.

Answer (score 0):

Before querying the data from mongodb, it would make sense to understand how data can be stored in mongodb. you have different ways to load data in mongodb for OTLP applications from operational, data life cycle perspective. mongodb data model design largely influence application operational efficiency and its data life cycle.  ex. embedded documents,references

Example: Embedded documents , this example requires a single pass of query execution to retrieve the documents.

The document store looks like this

```
student collection : 

{
    id : "123",
    name : "Surendra",
    Age : "21",
    department {
        department : "CSE",
        hod : "Ramki"
    },
    college {
        collegeName : "SKU",
        city : "HYD"
    }
}

{
    id : "125",
    name : "Reddy",
    Age : "21",

    department {
        department : "EEE",
        hod : "Ramki"
    }

    college{
        collegeName : "SKU",
        city : "HYD"
    }
}
```

To retrieve all documents, the query looks like:

```
db.student.find({} , {id:1, name:1, age:1, department:1 , college:1 } )
```

Reference documents:  Various methods to implement references however it depends on the read/write mode of the application. Reference will require to issue multiple queries to get the documents. i.e. multiple request to server from your client app.

The following example includes a child document in a parent document.

Example:

```
Student collection:
{
    student_id : "123",
    name : "Surendra",
    Age : "21",
    college_id : objectId(College_Id),
    Department_id : objectId(Department_Id)
}

Department collection : 
{
    Department_Id = objectId(),
    department : "CSE",
    hod : "Ramki"
}


Collecge Collecton :
{
    College_Id = objectId(),
    collegeName : "SKU",
    city : "HYD"
}

var pass1 = db.department.find({})
var dept = db.student.find({"department_id": {"$in": pass1}})
```